# Conjugation of quaternions

Tags: proof-verification, quaternions

This proof is *extreeeeemely* boring, but still I must get it right.

---

Let $x = x_0 + x_1 i + x_2 j + x_3 k \in \mathbb{H}$ (the Hamilton quaternions). Conjugation is defined as:
$$x^\ast = x_0 - x_1 i - x_2 j - x_3 k \, .$$
Show that for any $x, y\in \mathbb{H}$:
$$(x y)^\ast = y^\ast x^\ast$$
*Proof:* We use a different notation, let $$i_0 = 1, \quad i_1 = i, \quad i_2 = j, \quad i_3 = k \, .$$ Then we have 
$$i_1^2 = i_2^2 = i_3^2 = -1, \quad i_1 i_2 = -i_2 i_1 = i_3, \quad i_2 i_3 = -i_3 i_2 = i_1 \quad \text{and}\quad i_3 i_1 = -i_1 i_3 = i_2 \, .$$
For $r, s \geq 1$ and $r \neq s$ we see:
$$ (i_r i_s)^\ast = - (i_r i_s) = i_s i_r  = (-i_s)  (-i_r ) = i_s^\ast  i_r ^\ast \, .$$
This holds in general for all $0 \leq r, s \leq 3$ (the other cases are easily checked). Finally we get:

$$(x y)^\ast = \Biggl(\Bigr(\sum_{r=0}^3 x_r i_r\Bigl) \cdot \Bigr(\sum_{s=0}^3 y_s i_s\Bigl) \Biggr)^\ast =$$
$$= \Biggl(\sum_{r, s = 0}^3 x_r y_s i_r i_s \Biggr)^\ast = \sum_{r, s = 0}^3 x_r y_s (i_r i_s)^\ast =  \sum_{r, s = 0}^3 x_r y_s i_s^\ast i_r^\ast =$$
$$ = \Bigr(\sum_{s=0}^3 y_s i_s^\ast \Bigl) \cdot \Bigr(\sum_{r=0}^3 x_r i_r^\ast\Bigl) = y^\ast x^\ast \, .$$ $\square$

---

Everything ok?
Thank you!

Comment: it looks fine to me. the part: $(i_r i_s)^\ast = - (i_r i_s) = i_s i_r  = (-i_s)  (-i_r ) = i_s^\ast  i_r ^\ast \, $ is the *crucial* part as it reduced the tiresome job of checking by first multiplying and then... nice!!

Comment: Are you familiar with expressing a quaternion as the sum of a scalar and a vector?